# dimensions of vector spans added together

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Suppose you know that $\dim \langle v_1, v_2,.., v_n \rangle = m$ and $\dim \langle u_1,...,u_n \rangle=k$. What would the possible dimensions for $$\langle v_1+u_1, v_2 + u_2,..., u_n+v_n \rangle$$ be?

I was thinking of splitting it up into cases, like when $m>k$, $m<k$, $m=k$ but I'm not sure how it would affect the dimensions. I am thinking that if $m<k$, then the dimension would just be $k$ as it is the bigger one, and similar to the $m<k$ case. But I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: One has an easy upper bound of $m+k$ but the lower bound could be $0$ (why?).

Comment: Also, if $m\neq k$ then the lower bound of $0$ is not sharp (hint: consider linear dependence/independence of the vectors before and after addition).

Comment: Upper bound is $n$, which is greater than, or equal, to the maximum of $m,k$. Lower bound is zero. I think pretty much anything could happen.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand how the linear dependence/independence changes after the addition. Do they become linearly dependent after the addition?

Answer (score 1):

We can give a sharp upper bound of $m+k$ and sharp lower bound of $\lvert m-k\rvert $. I will show it for $m\geq k$ without loss of generality.

Let $V=\langle v_1,\cdots,v_n\rangle$ and $U=\langle u_1,\cdots, u_n\rangle,$ and $W=\langle v_1+u_1,\cdots,v_n+u_n \rangle.$

Using the formula for
dim$(V+U)$ and the fact that $W\subseteq V+U$ gives the upper bound.
For the lower bound the idea is that if, without loss of generality, $\{v_1,\cdots,v_k\}$ is a basis for $V$, then at most $k$ of the vectors in $\{u_1,\cdots,u_m\}$ can satisfy $u_i=-v_i$. Then the dimension of $W$ would be $m-k$ (Why?). Think then of how to construct every possibility between these bounds using a similar construction, they are all possible.